# How can I make an array from table columns in plsql

Tags: arrays, oracle, plsql

I have a table and there is a column and I get this column values like this with my code:

```
100
533
523
634
552
.
.
.
```

There are many rows like this and then I want make that like one row `(100,533,634,552,.,.,.,.)` add all of them to `v_products` or to an array. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```sql
v_products  varchar2(4000);

for c in (select distinct ugb.product_code
          into v_products 
          from uat.product_grup ug,uat.product_grup_con ugb
          where ug.product_grup_code like '%PRODUCT' )
loop
  v_products  := c.product_code;
  dbms_output.put_line(v_products);
end loop;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want them as a string then use `LISTAGG`.

```sql
DECLARE
  v_products  varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG( product_code, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY product_code )
  INTO   v_products
  FROM   (
    select distinct ugb.product_code
    from   uat.product_grup ug
           CROSS JOIN uat.product_grup_con ugb
    where ug.product_grup_code like '%PRODUCT'
  );
END;
/
```

If you want them as a collection (or `VARRAY`) then use `BULK COLLECT INTO`:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE product_code_list IS TABLE OF uat.product_grup_con.product_code%TYPE;
  v_products product_code_list;
BEGIN
  select distinct ugb.product_code
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_products
  from   uat.product_grup ug
         CROSS JOIN uat.product_grup_con ugb
  where ug.product_grup_code like '%PRODUCT';
END;
/
```

*(An aside, are you sure you want a legacy comma join without a correlating join condition in the `WHERE` clause, which is equivalent of am ANSI `CROSS JOIN`? Without a join condition, all you are doing is getting every `product_code` value from the `uat.product_grup_con` table. What you probably want is an `INNER JOIN`.)*

Comment: Sir when i use it like this : `SELECT LISTAGG( product_code , ',') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY product_code )` it is working thanks. i think you should update your answer like this.